# how to transfer everything from one icloud to another icloud in same iphone

Tags: ios, icloud

i want to transfer everything from one iCloud to another one in same iphone. i want to finish iCloud and i want to have a new one.
is there any one to help me?

Comment: Apple support? What specifically is "everything"

Answer (score 3):

You cannot transfer **everything** from one Apple ID to another.

Documents, photos, yes... apps, books, music etc, no.
The ID that purchased those [even free apps, *even the iDevice itself*] is locked to the Apple ID that purchased them & can never be transferred. The only alternative would be to wipe all the old data & set up as a new device, then repurchase the things belonging to the old ID. [This would also require the permission [password etc] of the ID giving up the device.

If all you really require is to change the email address associated with your ID, then you can do that - the ID itself is not dependant on any given email address [in fact it doesn't even have to **be** an email address, it's just easier to think that way]

See Apple KB : [Change your Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/HT202667) for full details.

Answer (score 0):

I move things from one iCloud folder to another using PathFinder.  It requires a mac and it's not free, although they give you 30 day trial period.  I have used it for years and bought the few additional upgrades that weren't free.  It's published by Cocoatech and allows you to see the source and target in side-by-side windows.  You can use a single command to move one file, a group of files or everything from one window to another.
http://www.cocoatech.com will answer any other questions.

Comment: I think the OP meant "everything", not just a few documents. I think, though this answer covers some aspects, it really doesn't feel like what they're actually asking for... which is, of course, not possible...